# "message": "Sandbox subdomains are for test purposes only. Please add your own domain or add the address to authoriz LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, mailgun

i got this error when i try to test method in my controller

```
 GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client error: `POST https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandbox22f99fb37d4a4953a7b8d84cf89d1147.mailgun.org/messages.mime` resulted in a `400 BAD REQUEST` response:
{
  "message": "Sandbox subdomains are for test purposes only. Please add your own domain or add the address to authoriz (truncated...)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the sandbox domain. You need to verify your own domain or verify the recipient in order to send an email to others.They are for test, not for API implementation

Read more : https://documentation.mailgun.com/faqs.html#how-do-i-pick-a-domain-name-for-my-mailgun-account

Follow the link to add recipients: https://mailgun.com/app/testing/recipients

Comment: This is work with other members in team so this locally happen to me ?
I mean when i change or verify this  will not affect to others ?

Comment: and for this https://mailgun.com/app/testing/recipients it request from me email and password what  should I enter ?